# Django + React as ecommerce shop

Tags: python, django, e-commerce

I have been learning Django and React for some time now. As part of my learning, I've decided to work on building my own store so I don't use Shopper anymore.
Can you recommend any ready-made ecommerce framework where I can add React as frontend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been doing some research along these same lines. It really depends on what you want to do with your store. If you're already familiar with React and aren't concerned about having multiple vendors, I'd suggest Saleor 3.0. The project used to use Django but has recently transitioned to a headless architecture with GraphQL.Since it's all decoupled you can use whatever frontend you want. I've seen some nice React and Next.js examples.

from [Saleor Github Repository](https://github.com/saleor/saleor):

> A modular, high performance, headless e-commerce platform built with Python, GraphQL, Django, and React.

[Saleor.io website](https://saleor.io/) has a live demo and you can request a sandbox.

If you're looking to build a marketplace with multiple vendors it seems like SpreeCommerce is a solid option. It's built on Ruby but also can use anything for the storefront

from [Spree Github Repository](https://github.com/spree/spree):

> Open Source headless multi-language/multi-currency/multi-store eCommerce platform

There are also a lot of 3rd party apps/plugins for Spree that extend the functionality.

[Spreecommerce.org](https://spreecommerce.org/)

Answer (score 0):

**> Best frontend framworks for ecommerce**

**REACT AKA React.js & ReactJS (React on GiftHub; React on StackOverflow):**
React is used to build user interfaces and UI components. It will render data only to DOM, so additional libraries need to be used for routing and state management.

**Advantages:**

**Time-saving:** individual React components can be re-used any time without any impact on system.

**Smooth system operation for user & developer:** virtual DOMs help updates to go seamlessly.

**Extensive recourses:** open-source community keeps creating tools, libraries, guides.

**Disadvantages:**

**Steep learning curve:** it does take longer to master it than Angular or Vue; not a one-day-exercise.

**VUE.JS [Vue JS on GiHub]:**
With 7,7 million monthly downloads, Vue.js is a rising star among JavaScript frameworks for building user interfaces. It’s hugely popular with Chinese developers to the extent that some of the material & forum discussions are only available in Chinese.

**Advantages:**

**Small-sized:** Vue framework is quick to download, great for SEO and UX.

**User-friendly & easy to learn:** extremely agile and straightforward, Vue is favored by developers due to its simplicity.

**Exhaustive documentation:** Vue.js docs are concise and well-structured.

**Browser extensions** help you to work with different individual components.

**Disadvantages:**

**Young community:** not as mature as other veterans of the framework offers, this community is still growing.

**Flexibility-paralysis:** too much flexibility within one team may lead to contradictory approaches that cancel each other out.

**ANGULAR:**
This popular open-source Google-created JavaScript-based framework employs MVC architecture for single web page applications.

**Advantages:**

**Less coding time:** data models take less time to write and there’s no need to modify controllers, but use filters instead.

**Two-way data binding:** the framework provides a seamless projection of models that saves developers' efforts.

**Testing:** the testing function is significantly simplified and is designed to be a nearly inherent function.
Great MVC

**Disadvantages:**

**Security:** the absence of server authorization and authentication leads to security issues.

**Memory leakage:** potential memory leakage that leads to slowdowns and crashes.

Comment: Please add some explanation for why these frameworks are good for ecommerce, especially the specific needs of ecommerce they address. Also point out any weaknesses frameworks may have that a potential user might want to be aware of.

Comment: I added some advantages and disadvantages.